# Gradle custom plugin: how to add custom dependency

Tags: java, maven, gradle, plugins, groovy

I've read a lot of information about this issue, but no luck.

I writing a custom plugin. My plugins use external dependency (GSON).

My plugin: https://pastebin.com/FBG0zVed

```
group = 'se.thinkcode.gradle'
version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'maven'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
   compile gradleApi()
   compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
   testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
   mavenLocal()
}

// try to add GSON to plugin dependencies
project.dependencies.ext.pluginDeps = {
  project.fileTree("C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads")
}

dependencies {
   compile pluginDeps()
}

// try to add GSON to plugin dependencies
project.configurations.compile.allDependencies;

// try to add GSON to plugin dependencies
project.buildscript {

 repositories {
     mavenCentral()
     jcenter()
 }

  dependencies {
     classpath "net.saliman:gradle-cobertura-plugin:1.1.2"
     classpath 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
  }
}
```

When I apply my plugin to another project I get an error: 
[image: When I apply my plugin to another project I get an error]

LOG info level: https://pastebin.com/raw/7q6KQ97m

Debug: https://pastebin.com/raw/Jn9MZXbm

How I can correctly add the dependency to my plugin?

Comment: Run with --info or --debug as it says. There is not enough information there to determine the problem. You could also show us the code or better yet create an [MCVE].

Comment: Questions must standalone. Post code here please.

Comment: Done. Let me know if you need more.

Comment: @JavaDude Did you figure this out?